# Firebase admin - Uncaught TypeError: class heritage events_1.EventEmitter is not an object or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, firebase-authentication, jwt

I use Firebase for logging using Google, it works using Typescript. But I want to pass token generated by Firebase to backend (Golang) to verify that the login is valid using firebase.

To do that I followed instructions to create JWT using `firebase-admin` but when I use it to create JWT I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: class heritage events_1.EventEmitter is not an object or null
    js api-request.js:690
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js credential-internal.js:25
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js lifecycle.js:24
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js firebase-namespace.js:21
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js default-namespace.js:19
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    js index.js:19
    __require2 chunk-AUZ3RYOM.js:18
    <anonymous> firebase-admin.js:145236
```

So how to get this work if `firebase-admin` doesn't work?

```js
import { UserCredential, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth"
import { auth, googleAuthProvider } from "./firebase_app"
import admin from "firebase-admin"

/**
 * UserCredential with JWT
 */
export type UserCredsWithJWT = UserCredential & {
    jwt: string
}

/**
 * Sign in with Google
 * @returns {Promise<UserCredsWithJWT>} UserCredential
 */
export const signInWithGoogle = async (): Promise<UserCredsWithJWT> => {
    try{
        const creds = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider)
        const jwt = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(creds.user.uid)

        return {
            ...creds,
            jwt: jwt,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed just little more time to explore firebase.auth() to found method to send JWT to backend... No need for `Firebase-admin`

```js
import { UserCredential, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth"
import { auth, googleAuthProvider } from "./firebase_app"

/**
 * UserCredential with JWT
 */
export type UserCredsWithJWT = UserCredential & {
    jwt: string
}

/**
 * Sign in with Google
 * @returns {Promise<UserCredsWithJWT>} UserCredential
 */
export const signInWithGoogle = async (): Promise<UserCredsWithJWT> => {
    try{
        const creds = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider)
        const jwt = await auth.currentUser?.getIdToken()

        if(!jwt){
            throw new Error("No JWT from Firebase")
        }

        return {
            ...creds,
            jwt,
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
```

Have a nice day